# Haskell Recursion Function

Tags: haskell, recursion

So, what I try to do is to define *recursively* a function that calculates how much money I have after **n** years, if I start with an amount **a** and receive **p** percent of interest per year.

```
interest (n,a,p)
 | n > 0          = interest (n-1,a,p)
       where a = (a*p)/100
 | otherwise      = a
```

And it gives me this error:

```
E:\\Module1\week3\scripts.hs:35:2: error: parse error on input `|'
   |
35 |  | otherwise      = a
   |  ^
```

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Although that is not the error, defining functions that are not "*curried*" are rather uncommon in Haskell. Typically the functions are defined as `interest n a p = ...`, and thus called with `interest (n-1) a p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` can only be used after *all* the guards, and applies to all of them. For instance

```
f x y =
  | x > 0     = g a + x   -- a is visible here
  | otherwise = h a + y   -- and here
  where a = x + y
```

Further, note that your `where a = (a*p)/100` will likely lead to non-termination, since `a` is recursively defined in terms of itself (`(a*p)/100`). You should use a new variable name e.g. `a' = (a*p)/100`.
It is in general a bad idea to "redefine" an outer variable in Haskell: turning on warnings with the `-Wall` flag helps in detecting these issues.

Finally, note that you can also use `let` instead of `where`, and use that inside any expression. For instance

```
f x y =
  | x > 0 =
     let a = x + y
     in g a + x
  | otherwise = y  -- a is not visible here
```

One could even write

```
(let a = x + y in g a) + x
```

albeit I can not recommend this style.

Comment: I succeeded using if instead of guards. I will try this way, as well. Thank you very much!